# VS shortcut to AnkhSvn show changes

Tags: visual-studio, svn, diff, ankhsvn

Is there or can I add a keyboard shortcut to AnkhSvn Show Changes (from the context menu) for the current file in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 4):

This may not have been possible at the time; but it is now possible.

The command for show changes is:
ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.SourceControl.Svn.Compare

Note: This will not display the diff if there are no changes to the currently opened file.

Reference:

http://igorredchuk.blogspot.ca/2014/12/setting-keyboard-shortcuts-for-ankhsvn.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is not possible right-away. I think best you can achieve is to bind **File.CommitItem** to your preferred hot-key which will show *Commit to Subversion* window.

Answer (score -2):

FYI: if you use VisualSVN then you can right-click in Visual Studio's code editor to open a context menu and then select **Show Differences** or **Show Log** commands.

The first one will open diff tool for the opened file, the second one will show revision history for the file.